# Flag one's own question without reputation limit

Tags: feature-request, flags, new-users, privileges

Can we allow a user with fewer than 15 reputation points to **flag his own question** for moderator attention? I feel that this should be similar to the ability to vote to delete answers and questions: a reputation limit is needed when it is about *other people's* questions, but a reputation limit should not be necessary for being about the user's own questions.

Possible application is [something like this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/flagging-for-moderator-attention).

Comment: If this were allowed, I would expect to see more new users flagging their own questions just because they didn't get good answers. (This already happens a couple of times a week on SO.)

Comment: @mmyers: but the moderators will just dismiss the flags as invalid, and their flag-weight will soon sink to oblivion...

Comment: @WillieWong: I haven't seen any practical result of a low flag weight.  I'd rather punch them through the internets, but that feature request is still status-postponed.

Comment: Also, there always will be bad users. But I would like to help out any potential good users to make better use of the site as much as possible. I think that the more easily the moderators can address the issues the new users face, the quicker the new users will be acclimated to the community and become contributors of good content.

Comment: @mmyers: that's what flag weight is for then, right? <10rep users could be given a very low flag weight until their flags are approved or they gained some rep

Comment: @will if flag weight gets to zero their flags are permanently discarded

Comment: @Jeff: out of curiosity, forgetting that I am the OP for a second, in the abstract scenario where I post a comment, Will posts one, and I post another, is it at all possible to use the @notification to send a comment to Will? In other words, would @Will match him or match me?

Comment: @willie that's a good point; I believe the longer name will block the shorter name from matching if it is chronologically last to appear. I had never considered that before today..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think I can support this. There's too much risk allowing anonymous and low-rep users to flag their own content.

I suggest if new users need that level of assistance, they email the address at the bottom of every page -- or better yet, earn 15 reputation.

Comment: Fair enough. The Jeff has spoken.