# Let the user access their flag history when they are suspended

Tags: feature-request, support, account-suspension, flag-history

When a user is suspended, it is not possible for them to access their flag history. I do not understand why it is like this. Simply restricting the flag history access makes no sense in my opinion.

[image]

Please let the user access their flag history when they are suspended.

Comment: I think you can actually access that page if you know the URL, right? https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current

Comment: @Glorfindel I have no clue. Maybe you can use your powers and do some science?

Comment: I can suspend you for science :P

Comment: @Glorfindel haha... ok. But just for 10 minutes. Is that OK?

Comment: I'll suspend a sockpuppet of mine. But first I have a hard drive to rescue ...

Comment: @Glorfindel OK. Take your time and let me know :)

Comment: That's a good proposal, but there is a simple rationale behind the inability to access flags - since you have your rep temporarily set to 1, the system treats you like a user without all the privileges the rep gives. Does not mean suspension should not have been special-cased, though. Maybe it's worth a userscript if the URL is still accessible

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Actually <15 rep users can flag on their own posts. But you are right that [they can't access their flag history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290061/323179).

Comment: Why on earth would a suspended user need access to their flag-history? What are they going to do with it while being suspended? Heck, what are you doing with your flag-history while not suspended? If access to your flag-history is precious to you then don't get suspended. Problem solved.

Comment: @rene well, cooldown suspensions ain't exactly crimes against humanity, whereas the user might have a bunch of pending flags in the meantime theycwould want to check up on. Can't say it's in any way essential, just something that would be "nice to have" for some.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I was just raging on Meta about all these mods wrongfully declining my flags, so yeah, while I cool down let's see what else they decline ...

Comment: @rene nothing more soothing than brooding over flags during suspension (not that I know what it's like, thankfully) :) Still, why not give them access to the history page? That said, I don't see this as a valuable feature to spend dev time on either, maybe that's another userscript idea to go on my list

Comment: @rene based on your logic suspended user should be blocked from even reading any post on the site they're suspended (because they can't vote it, or do any action - waste of time!). And sorry but that logic, in my humble opinion, is wrong and incorrect.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar yeah, that would be awesome! But wait, they could simply open the site in private mode and still read posts, that is not good! We need to send a virus to their PC, their network, their ISP, block it all. In all seriousness: I still don't have seen a valid argument why this "feature" would be needed, iow what benefit it has. In general I'm not in favor of spending dev time on improving the UX for suspended users. There are plenty of other small things to fix for a majority of regular users. Let's focus on that.

Comment: @rene what's wrong with someone who want to go over they past activity? Why let them see their past questions, answers, comments, whatever, and not flags? I really don't get it. And for the record, can block all IP addresses used by the suspended user, so they won't be able to see any page on the site, and get "**YOU ARE SUSPENDED, GO DO SOMETHING ELSE**" with blinking, of course. That would surely make them learn from their hideous mistakes.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar you forgot marquee ... okay, fair points. Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @rene due to worldwide shortage, ice cream will be served only in 6-8 days.

Comment: @Glorfindel Any updates? Did you suspend your sock puppet?

Comment: @RandomPerson sorry, yes, I tested it and the flag summary is still accessible. So it's just the profile page which doesn't show the link.