# Why have flag options for comments disappeared from my account?

Tags: support, flags

I don't know the reason why flag options have disappeared from my comment section.

[image]

Is low reputation a reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least [15 reputation to flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), you have 6 when I checked (which, naturally will change over time), so looks like it.

Kinda odd that flag's visible on the question itself, but if you had the reputation, it should show up on comments on hover.

Comment: oh, I was thinking the flag option on the question - but I don't have any 1 rep accounts to test

Comment: oh, that's the case too, but OP cannot flag at all anyway

Comment: @polygeo in my case i couldn't see any flags even when my mouse is over the comment

Comment: Users can flag their own post even with 1 rep (see it mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228288/should-1-reputation-users-be-able-to-flag-their-own-posts)), same way they can post in per-site meta with 1 rep if linking to their existing post.

Comment: @user7982827 I was replying to "Kinda odd that flag's visible on the question itself" part in the answer. (You can flag your own post, but not the comments on it)

Comment: Ah. That makes sense

Comment: What shadowwizard said in response to me