# Under what circumstances can a user flag a post without them having at least 15 reputation?

Tags: support, flags, owner

I was going through my old posts on HSM Meta and found [this one](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/312/10106) where I was informed about a user getting a [Citizen Patrol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) badge without them even having the minimum requirement of 15 reputation for flagging a post.

The moderator's reply to my query was:

> "Under certain circumstances a new user is able to flag posts with less than the required 15 reputation. In this instance the user in question did indeed submit a flag. You can even see from their profile that they have 1 helpful flag. (The flag wasn't yet handled when this question was posted but has since been dealt with.)".

My question is: Under what circumstances can a user flag a post when they don't have at least 15 reputation?

I tried finding a duplicate post here on MSE. Such information may help a lot of new users who want to contribute constructively in their initial days at SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- New users can always flag their own posts for moderator attention: [Should 1-reputation users be able to flag their own posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228288/295232)
- New users can flag *comments* on their own post, or comments on answers to their own question: [Allow new users to flag comments on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311459/295232)

Note that the latter can be a reason for the "1 helpful flag" but not for the [Citizen Patrol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) badge since it requires you to flag a *post*, not a comment (and it doesn't even need to be helpful).